# Refresh ggplot after observe event in select input

Tags: r, charts, shiny, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar chart which change depending of the value inserted in a combo box (select input).

I control the select input with observe event, but I can't refresh the ggplot.

This is what I got: #comobox to pick the number of experts

```
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_experts", label = "Choose:",
           choices = c("All", "Top50","Top10"), selected = "All")
)

 observeEvent(input$n_experts, {
     if(input$n_experts == "Top10"){
          data <<- read.csv(*csvFile*)
          ggplot(data, aes(x = V1, y = V2, fill = winner)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
          scale_fill_manual(values=c("local" = "dark blue","visitor" = "red"))+
    coord_flip()
    print("button top pressed")
  }else if(input$n_experts == "All"){
     data <<- read.csv(*csvFile*)
     ggplot(data, aes(x = V1, y = V2, fill = winner)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("local" = "dark blue","visitor" = "red"))+
      coord_flip()
    print("button all pressed")
 }
   })
```

**Code Edited to the given example**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(

  inputPanel(
    selectInput("n_experts", label = "Choose:",
                choices = c("All", "Top50","Top10"), selected = "All")
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot2"))
  )

server <- function(input,output){

  dat <- reactive({
    input <- input$n_experts
    if(input == "All"){
      info <<- read.csv(file1)
    }else if (input == "Top10"){
      info <<- read.csv(file2)
    }

  })

  info[["winner"]] = ifelse(metapicks[["V2"]] >= 0, "local", "visitor")

  output$plot2<-renderPlot({
                 ggplot(info, aes(x = V1, y = V2, fill = winner)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
                      scale_fill_manual(values=c("local" = "dark blue","visitor" = "red"))+
                      coord_flip()},height = 600,width = 800)}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: you need to render the plot check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969659/shiny-reactive-ggplot-output

Comment: I adapted the code. But when I run the app, it does not find the variable info, which actually is changing depending on the select input. What is the problem??

Comment: You need to put dat() instead of info in ggplot

Comment: also it s a bad idea to call something input, change it to n_experts if you really want to change it

Comment: Oh, sure. I forgot that. That works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok. I will try that ;)