# Interactive plot: Manipulate contents of a ggplot2 plot with a sliding bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

**Edit**: Thank you to Javier for his suggestion. I forgot to mention that I would like to incorporate this interactive plot into a report / dashboard, so something that works with a HTML document from RMarkdown would be ideal, but a dashboard solution would also be fine.

Consider the following plots; the red line represents the actual data, while the green line plots predictions generated by a model:

[image]

The predictions of two different models are displayed; one trained over the first 100 hours, and the other over the first 216 hours. Predictions are then generated for the unseen data-points, then plotted.

What I would like to do, is train `n` models, eg. one every 12 hours in an expanding window fashion. After having done this, I would like to present the results in an interactive fashion where the user can click/slide something to move the vertical line back and forth, thereby changing which model's predictions are displayed. The point would be to intuitively show the effect of different training lengths.

I'm new to shiny and interactive plots in R; can this be done without too much trouble?

Comment: Check out the gallery, there are many many examples: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/ And there are many examples on SO, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969659/shiny-reactive-ggplot-output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with the example at the bottom of [this link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-start.html).

```
library(shiny)

sliderInput("n", "Training length:", 100, min=24, max= 11*24)

renderPlot({
  plotPredictCurve(data= df, trainLength= input$n)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You can with the `manipulate` package for quick interactive plots. `Shiny` requires more fine-tuning and it is more time-consuming.

Here is a reproducible example for you to test out: 
This creates the slider bar:

```
library(manipulate)
manipulate(plot(1:x), x = slider(1, 100))
```

Put your code here for the creation of the interactive plot:

```
manipulate(
  plot(cars, xlim = c(0, x.max), type = type, ann = label),
  x.max = slider(10, 25, step=5, initial = 25),
  type = picker("Points" = "p", "Line" = "l", "Step" = "s"),
  label = checkbox(TRUE, "Draw Labels"))
```

[image: plot1]

Check out the CRAN manipulate package for more information: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/manipulate/index.html

Comment: Cool, will check it out. I'm guessing this functionality won't carry over into a HTML document generated by R Markdown; so if I want to present it neatly I'll have to go the shiny route?

Comment: Oh i'm not too sure if this works within the RMarkdown script! Haven't tried that before