# R Shiny- How to apply user inserted text to run a function (R code) and produce final ggplot output

Tags: user-interface, ggplot2, shiny

I have a basic R code where, within the code, a user can enter a country name "Argentina". Using that value/name, the code will run an analysis for the "Argentina" subset of the pre-loaded data. Finally, the code will produce a simple ggplot showing results.

I have tried to make this code into a Shiny App, however I cannot get it to work properly. My main issue is that I cannot seem to get the data analysis in the Server section to work, which should subsequently feed into the plotting code. More importantly, I cannot seem to get the user inputted country name to feed into my data analysis.

Without going into the detail of the code, could someone kindly point me in the right direction of how one would do this in Shiny? e.g.

1) Field for user input;

2) Use that user input as an object used in the code;

3) subsequently run the analysis (whatever it might be); and

4) use the final analysis data frame in ggplot for a figure output to be displayed in the shiny app.

Many thanks for your assistance and time.

Please see my shinny code currently used, with reproducible data using MTcars

```
library(shiny)

# Some Sample data to run app using mtcars
mtcars$Primary<- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$Area <- "Argentina"
mtcars$Y2016<- mtcars$mpg
mtcars$Element <- "Gross Production Value (constant 2004-2006 million US$)"

# Defining UI ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(

          # App title ----
          headerPanel("Subsector Selection Tool"),

          # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
          sidebarPanel(

            # Input: Country name
            textInput("country", "Please enter country name", "")#,
          ),

          # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
          mainPanel("")
)


# Define server logic to plot various variables against mpg ----
server <- function(input, output) {

 #Trying to make user inputed country name into an object to be used in 
 "reactive" code below, which in turn is be used to make dataset for graphing
 country_interest <- reactive({
 paste(input$country)
 })


#Here I am trying to make the data analysis code run and create desired 
dataset for graphing, and subsetting for country selected by user
Value_c_e_PRIM_x  <- reactive({

Value_c <- Value[which(Value$Area==country_interest),]
Value_c_e <- Value_c[which(Value_c$Element=="Gross Production Value (constant 2004-2006 million US$)"),]
Value_c_e_PRIM$Primary <- Value_c_e_PRIM[,120]
Value_c_e_PRIM[,120] <- NULL

Value_c_e_PRIM <-  Value_c_e_PRIM %>% group_by(Primary,Element) %>% summarise_at(vars(Y2016), sum)

Value_c_e_PRIM$Category <- "Value of Production"
Value_c_e_PRIM$Value <- Value_c_e_PRIM$Y2016
Value_c_e_PRIM <-  Value_c_e_PRIM %>% group_by(Category,Primary) %>% summarise_at(vars(Value), mean)



})


#Graphing section, if  Ihave the dataset "Value_c_e_PRIM_x" pre-loaded (e.g. not derived in code above), the figure is successfully shown in the output.
output$plot <- renderPlot({

Graph_data <- Value_c_e_PRIM_x 
Graph_data$Score_type <- "Competitiveness Score"
Graph_data$`Competitiveness Score` <- round(Graph_data$Value, 2)

title1 <-paste("Competitiveness\nby",paste0(country_interest),"Subsector")
mycol <-c("red", "yellow", "#006600")

ggplot(data = Graph_data, aes(x = Score_type, y = reorder(Primary,Value), fill=Value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Value), colour= "white")+
  geom_text(data=Graph_data,aes(y=Primary, x= Score_type, label=Value))+
  labs(title =(paste0(title1)),y = "", x = "")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = mycol)+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

 })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible since we don't have access to your ```.csv``` file. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to know how to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, I have added a sample dataset to run the code using mtcars

Comment: your code is quite complicated for what you're trying to do, you should simplify it (you don't need to show all the data manipulations, once you know how to make one in shiny, you know how to make several of them). Also, there are already answers about how to make reactive [plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969659/shiny-reactive-ggplot-output), [datatable](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html), etc.